# Time value only format and input

Tags: excel, time

I would like to format a cell for time only display and input.

When I enter in the time into the cell as

```
11.50
```

what I then see in the cell is

```
7:12:00 AM
```

when I go into the cell it shows

```
11/01/1900  7:12:00 AM
```

Is there a way I can enter only the time into the cell and it will show the correct time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the time as `11:50`  assuming the colon is your time separator in your country.  That entry will be interpreted as `11:50 AM`